# How can i drag a view from a fragment to an activity to draw to a canvas

Tags: android, android-fragments, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have a fragment view pager adapter overlaying an activity with a canvas, one of the fragments in the view pager are full of imageviews, i want to drag an imageview from that fragment and drop it on the activities canvas, I've followed a tutorial on vogella and i don't think i completely understand everything its doing so far i can grab the image and drag it around the screen, if i drop it on the canvas nothing happens.

i have created a method in my drawing view class (custom DrawView) that draws on the canvas for dropping an object but it seems its never called

```
public boolean dropObject(DragEvent event, Bitmap bitmap){
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            invalidate();

            System.out.println("DrawingView ACTION DROP");


            drawCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,touchX,touchY,canvasPaint);

            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

i call this from the fragments DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

```
sqBtn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.drag_sqre);
    sqBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(sqBtn);

            v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
            return true;
        }
    });

    sqBtn.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
                    if (dropEventNotHandled(event)) {
                        sqBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    // Do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Do nothing
                    System.out.println("Drawbrushfragment ACTION DROP");
                    DrawActivity.drawView.dropObject(event, sqBtn.getDrawingCache());
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And heres my OnTouchListener

```
    sqBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(sqBtn);

                sqBtn.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, sqBtn, 0);
                //sqBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone?

Comment: If there is only a single destination, do you need to do drag & drop?  If you can just tap the image you need & make it go to the the canvas, it just fragment to activity communications. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html (for frag to frag comms but is useful for frag to activity)

Comment: Your quite right and I have swapped to just a click and then let the user move it around

Comment: I had something similar, multiple sources but one destination (all in the same fragment though) that I was implementing drag & drop.  Showing it to a friend, they said "why do I have to do this if it's going to only one place".